# How can I remove HTML code from a string in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use a mongodb command to remove certain values from a string?

I'm trying to clean up my data by removing the HTML coding in my data. I have the following data in my collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d557a8ce97863222b85f9cf"), "description" : "<p><p><strong>Opdrachtspecificaties</strong><br>Referentienummer: BTIT23128<br>Omgeving: Rotterdam<br>Startdatum: z.s.m"}
```

I'm trying to remove the html code from "description" to let it look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d557a8ce97863222b85f9cf"),"description" : "Opdrachtspecificaties Referentienummer: B1234 Omgeving: Rotterdam Startdatum: z.s.m"}
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure as to whether `mongoDB` has a command to strip out html tags out of the box - have you tried the String `replace` method? As in `Obj.description.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, "")`

Answer (score 1):

As rags2riches said, is more easy to use the replace method instead of install a package.

You can try something like this:

```
db.collection //collection = your collection name
.then(tags => {
    tags.map(tag => {
        tag.description = tag.description.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, "")
        db.collection.save(tag) //collection = your collection name
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Not sure if the code will run because I don't tested it, but I'm pretty sure with the main idea. -> You can make use of JavaScript to execute some queries in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a migration script for this. Take the  field that  has html in it from db, remove html from string and update it back to db.

You can use this package [string-strip-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-strip-html)
check this [fiddle for exapmle](https://jsfiddle.net/amrendra_pcs007/4hf5ruyx/2/)

```
migrationScript.js
//get db connection
const db = require('db path');
// get collection for which you have to run migration
const model = require('model path');

const stripHtml = require('string-strip-html');

db.once('open', () => {
  removeHtmlAndUpdate();
});

const removeHtmlAndUpdate = async doc => {
  try {
    model
      .find({})
      .cursor()
      .on('data', async () => {
        //remove html from the monogdb fields
        doc.description = stripHtml(doc.description);

        //update the data back
        const res = await model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: doc._id }, doc, { new: true });
        console.log('res', res);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
};
```

Additional advice: please test this locally on your db dump before running it on production